# How to turn off display and keep this even mouse move (keep system running)?

Tags: windows-10, display

My friends often use TeamViewer to connect to my computer. They always take up a lot of time, so I want to keep the system running but turn off my PC monitor with no effect on the PC remote. When I tried to search on Google, I discovered something resembling Blacktop. But something is wrong with the PC remote; something is good, but when my friends move the mouse, it will turn on the monitor.
I appreciate your assistance.

Comment: When all else fails, just turn the monitor off manually.

Comment: Yes, but i'm using a laptop

Comment: @Dile so why can't you turn off the monitor? Any software to black out the screen or something would also apply to the teamviewer session.

Comment: something awkward to try is log off the computer when you're away, then start a remote desktop session instead (from your phone or something) for your teamviewer people to connect to. It shouldn't wake the monitor at least

Comment: I tried something but most of apps will affect to TeamViewer. It will close the connection or freeze in TeamViewer

Comment: It seems to me that the way TeamViewer works does not allow the system to be "headless" (as it binds to an actual video output?). Perhaps the best you can do is to dim the backlight as much as possible. (Or see if there's a way to configure teamviewer to work in a more remote login approach that it will have its own virtual display session?)

Answer (score 1):

Frame challenge: You've mentioned that you use a laptop, so why not just close it?

Go in to your Power Settings and disable any actions that happen when the screen is closed. After that, just close the laptop. You might still see some light coming out of the gap between the keyboard and the screen, but that's tiny.

Comment: Awesome! I found this here:https://www.hellotech.com/guide/for/how-to-keep-laptop-on-when-closed.

Comment: I find a prolem. when i close the desktop - TeamViewer will freeze

Answer (score 0):

TeamViewer just publishes your screen.
So whatever you do to the screen will also affect TeamViewer.

The only solution would be to cover the screen, if the light bothers you.